# how to insert data in foreign key along with other data in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a problem while inserting data into my MySQL database. The following error occurs:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`login`.`employees`, CONSTRAINT `employees_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`u_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

I have a table named `employees`:

```
+-------------+
|  employees  |
+-------------+
| id          |
| u_id        |  foreign key of table `user` field `id`
| firstname   |
| lastname    |
| city        |
| designation |
+-------------+
```

My form code:

```
class Application_Form_Login extends Zend_Form
{
public function init()
{
    $this->setName('Login');
    $this->setMethod('post');

    $username = $this->createElement('text','username');
    $username->setLabel('Username: *')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->setFilters(array('StringTrim','StringToLower'))
            ->getValidators(array('stringLength',false,array(0,50)));

    $password = $this->createElement('password','password');
    $password->setLabel('Password: *')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->setFilters(array('StringTrim'))
            ->getValidators(array('stringLength',false,array(0,50)));

    $submit = $this->createElement('submit','Sign in');
    $submit->setLabel('Sign in')
            ->setIgnore(true);

    $this->addElements(array($username,
                        $password,
                        $submit,));
}
}
```

This is my table model:

```
class Application_Model_Dbtables_Employees extends Zend_Db_Table
{
protected $_name = 'employees';
}
```

Here is my controller:

```
class EmployeeController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

public function init()
{
    /* Initialize action controller here */
}

public function indexAction()
{
    // action body
}

public function addAction()
{
    $emp = new Application_Model_Dbtables_Employees();
    $form = new Application_Form_employee();
    $this->view->form = $form;

    if($this->getRequest()->isPost())
    {
        $formdata = $this->_request->getPost();

          if($form->isValid($formdata))
          {
            unset($formdata['addemployee']);
            $emp->insert($formdata);
            $this->_redirect('Auth/home');
          }
          else
          {
            $this->view->errMsg = "Cound not able to insert data";
          }
    }
}
}
```

And my view file:

```
<?php
if(isset($this->errMsg)) {
echo $this->errMsg;
}
?>

<?php 
 echo $this->form;
?>
```

my employee from code

```
<?php
class Application_Form_employee extends Zend_Form
{
public function init()
{
    $this->setMethod('post');
    $this->setName('addemployee');

    $firstname = $this->createElement('text', 'firstname');
    $firstname->setLabel('Firstname: *')
                ->setRequired(true)
                ->setFilters(array('StringToLower'));

    $lastname = $this->createElement('text', 'lastname');
    $lastname->setLabel('Lastname: *')
                ->setRequired(true)
                ->setFilters(array('StringToLower'));

    $city = $this->createElement('select', 'city');
    $city->setLabel('city: ')
        ->setRequired(true)
        ->setMultiOptions(array(
                '' => '---select city---',
                'ahmedabad' => 'Ahmedabad',
                'Vadodara' => 'Vadodara',
                'Anand' => 'Anand',
                'Surat' => 'Surat'));
    $designation = $this->createElement('select', 'designation');
    $designation->setLabel('Designation: ')
                ->setMultiOptions(array(
                        'java' => 'Java developer',
                        'php' => 'PHP developer',
                        'unix' => 'Unix developer'));

    $submit = $this->createElement('submit', 'addemployee');
    $submit->setLabel('Add Employee')
            ->setIgnore(true);

    $this->addElements(array(
            $firstname,
            $lastname,
            $city,
            $designation,
            $submit,));
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Please post the Application_Form_employee code

Comment: added the employee form code.

Comment: In your controller, you do not store anything in the u_id field.  What should be in that field ?

Comment: when any user logged in. . .thay have id(u_id). and add employees (stroed in employees table). as user can add more than 1 employee and there is only 1 table for many employees .so others users have also their employees added. when logged in i store data in zend_auth_storage_session() and fetch the row and also id of the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way that I can think of to make it work.  Basically, you have a restriction where the DB needs a corresponding foreign key (u_id) when inserting a new entry in the employee table.  You pass on the form data but no u_id is passed.  So in your Application_Form_employee form, you could add a hidden field that holds the user id that is inserting the record:

```
$uId = $this->createElement('hidden', 'u_id');
$uId->setValue(Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity()->id);
//And when you add elements to your form, add this field
    $this->addElements(array(
            $firstname,
            $lastname,
            $city,
            $designation,
            $uId,
            $submit,));
```

I think this could do the trick.